# How can I edit/produce themed videos on Android (e.g. iMovie for Android)?

Tags: video

In video editting apps, is there something like iMovie, which allows you to make movies based on "themes"? I.e. stichs movie clips together on a theme like "princess" or "adventurer" and form an elaborate result?

Comment: Hi p.a. and welcome to Android Enthusiasts. "Is there a app for X?" questions are off-topic. I edited the title to stay within the scope of our FAQ.